# Passing a label as a string into a query through scenes JavaFX

Tags: javafx, parameter-passing

On my first scene the user selects a team from the table and on the next is info about this team.
My problem however is passing the string (stored as a label) into the next scene that shows the selected teams results.

```
public void goResults(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
     loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("TeamResults.fxml"));

     Parent tableViewParent = (Parent)loader.load();

     Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(tableViewParent);

   //access controller and call method
     TeamResultsController controller = loader.getController();
     controller.initData(teamLabel.getText());
```

This is me passing the team name (teamLabel) from scene 2 to scene 3 when the results button is selected.

```
private String team;

    public void initData(String teamName) {
         this.team = teamName;
```

This is the function im passing the label value into, and setting it to string team.

However, if i try print the team variable outside of this function, its set to null. How do i get it to hold the value outside of initData?

For example:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        try {
            Connection con = DBConnector.connect();
             ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT t1.title AS title, t2.title AS title2, g.score1, g.score2 FROM games g INNER JOIN teams AS t1 ON g.team1_id = t1.id INNER JOIN teams AS t2 ON g.team2_id = t2.id WHERE g.team1_id ="+team +"OR g.team2_id ="+team+"");
            while(rs.next()){
                reslist.add(new TeamResultsTable(rs.getString("title"), rs.getString("title2"), rs.getInt("score1"), rs.getInt("score2")));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

         title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeamResultsTable, String>("title"));
        title2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeamResultsTable, String>("title2"));
        score1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeamResultsTable, Integer>("score1"));
        score2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeamResultsTable, Integer>("score2"));

        gameTable.setItems(reslist);
```

I'm trying to pass it into this query (dont worry about a prepared statement for now).

What method would you recommend? I understand this is supposedly similar to other example threads but i'm yet to correlate it to mine. I apologize for my inexperience, but some sort of framework would be incredible.

However any help is great,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use the value at `initialize` because `initialize` called at `loader.load()` and in this time this is indeed `null` value.
you can do the query after `controller.initData(teamLabel.getText());` is get called, in new function(and call that function) or even inside `initData`

another not recommended option is to pass the controller as an object to the loader(and put all needed values before load), but if you do that you will have trouble to define the controller in the fxml file